# iis 8 stripping form data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a simple jQuery AJAX function

```
var tkn=getToken();  // user's session token
var dataString="token="+tkn;
console.log(dataString);

   $.ajax({    
      type: "POST",    
      url: "cgi/getCO.exe",
      error: ajaxError,    
      data: dataString,    
      success: function(r){
```

The only thing I'm passing to the CGI is the user's session token, which looks like:

```
token=12345678901234567890
```

Most of the time, this works fine. The console always shows what I'd expect.
Occasionally, nothing gets passed to the CGI.
It will error saying the user is bad, and when I look at what was passed (on a server log) it shows *nothing*.

My CGI code is an compiled EXE written in PowerBasic.
The receiver portion looks like this:

```
function PBMain()
   local sParams as string
   sParams=readCGI()
```

and the variable sParams is empty.

Though it's possible, I don't know how my code can be failing. I wonder if it's something in IIS like a MS update or something that is messing with me. I question this logic because I probably have 50 websites that use jQuery AJAX with PB EXE on the back end, and they all work fine. I have Windows 2012-R2 server running IIS 8.

My question : I'm out of ideas of how to troubleshoot this further. I know it may be hard to be specific so does anyone have any general ideas as to what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that my CGI was reading the data before IIS had the chance to send it completely. I fixed it by calling the Windows API GetFileDizeEX function until there was data to serve.

A full discussion at PowerBasic can be found here
http://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/programming-the-internet/743817-no-post-data-sometimes